# How to create/update/delete/query databases on a Mac?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, macos, rdbms

I work for a software company where I do customer support for a web-based CMS and a CRM back office. I have no background in programing, but I am trying to learn on my own. At work, it is a 100% Microsoft house. At home, all I have is a Mac.  When I'm at work, I sometimes have to write VERY simple ad-hoc SQL statements to do very simple things like recover accidentally deleted XML transactions etc. I do this in MS SSMS. At home, I am going through the W3Schools free SQL tutorials which has a web-based SQL Studio emulator. I'd like to be able to create tables, update the records, and just play around with writing query statements... but on my Mac. 
I know that Microsoft has Visual Studio, and Apple has Xcode. Microsoft has Windows Server, and Apple has macOS Server. Microsoft has MS SSMS, but does Apple just not have a RDBMS?

Comment: Why don't you simply use the most wide spread RDBMS, MySQL? Especially since you can use it on _all_ platforms and there is a huge range of additional software components supporting it.

Comment: Can't you get Microsoft Office for Mac if you want to use Access? I think they also have Ms SQL Server for mac. If you don't want to pay for it I guess you could use MySQL like @arkascha  mentions.

Comment: If you are not a techie avoid setting up a virtual environment on your apple toy - buy a windows box and install sql server developer edition.

Answer (score 3):

All SQL is not the same, you should learn the dialect you're using at work rather than generic SQL.

If you're all Microsoft, you'll probably want to read up on [MSSQL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ms_sql_server/index.htm), specifically.

W3Schools in particular is known to provide incomplete, misleading, and now and then downright incorrect information, I would advise to find another resource (like the one I linked above).

Good luck!

Comment: The biggest issue I have with the w3fools is that they have totally *ignored* the suggested improvements that I (and others) have made. Having misleading and incorrect information kind of goes with the turf... but as a resource that frequently tops google search results, its unconscionable that they either have no intention to, or have no workable process to improve the information with corrections or clarifications. +10. Unconscionable.

Answer (score 1):

**MySQL or PostgreSQL**

Can install them in macOS directly.

**MS SQL Server**
1. you can install a  virtual machine of windows on macOS， then install MS SQL  Server in windows system

2. Install a DB client  in macOS(Such as Datagrip,Navicat Premium,SQLPro Studio etc.) to connect SQL Server that installed in other computer.
3. [Run the SQL Server Docker image on Linux, Mac, or Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-docker)